# transform a list into rown in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode, pandas-explode

I recuperated my data from TMDB and i've reached to a dataframe that contains:
id (tmdb movie id), nameperson(nameof the each member of the cast), knownfor (movies they participated) and popularity (for each of the ppl).

[i've reached at this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0D4O.png)

My issue is that after the explodes, i arrived at the point where i have multiple lines with same id, but i havent managed to separate my actors etc in order to see their popularity by row.[image]

My goal is to have a dataframe:
id, nameperso , knownfor, popularity

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [**`pandas.Series`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) constructor with [**`pandas.Series.explode`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)
to explode all the columns that hold a list.

Try this :

```
out = df.set_index('id').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()

out.columns= out.columns.str.replace(r"\d+", "", regex=True) #to get rid of the suffix number
```

##### Output :

```
print(out.head())

     id       nameperso known_for popularity
0  1891     Mark Hamill    Acting     32.141
1  1891   Harrison Ford    Acting     26.614
2  1891   Carrie Fisher    Acting      8.532
3  1891     Mark Hamill    Acting     32.141
4  1891   Harrison Ford    Acting     26.614
```